# Shared library names have version extension that linker isn't looking for?

Tags: ld, rpm, dynamic-linking, dynamic-library

I have some shared libraries, most I believe installed via Red Hat packages: ncurses, cap, uuid, xml2.

```
[root@mycomputer~]# rpm -ql libuuid-2.23.2-43.el7_4.2.x86_64
/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1
/usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0
/usr/share/doc/libuuid-2.23.2
/usr/share/doc/libuuid-2.23.2/COPYING

> l /usr/lib64/*uuid*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 20040 Nov  9  2017 /usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    16 Jul  3  2018 /usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1 -> libuuid.so.1.3.0
```

A vendor's example program's makefile has `-luuid` on the link line, and the linker complains:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -luuid
```

I run `strace -f make ... >& makeout` to capture all the system calls made by make and its descendant processes.  `-f` means "follow child processes too.")

When I grep that output file for the string `uuid` I see it's never looking for a file with the **`.1`** extension.

```
[pid 21920] open("/opt/nmr/sap/sybaseASE/sybclient-16.0.3-7/OCS-16_0/lib/libuuid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/opt/nmr/sap/sybaseASE/sybclient-16.0.3-7/OCS-16_0/lib/libuuid.a", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/lib64/libuuid.a", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/libuuid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/libuuid.a", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/libuuid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/libuuid.a", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/lib/../lib64/libuuid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/lib/../lib64/libuuid.a", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/lib/../lib64/libuuid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/lib/../lib64/libuuid.a", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../libuuid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../libuuid.a", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64/libuuid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64/libuuid.a", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/lib64/libuuid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/lib64/libuuid.a", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/local/lib64/libuuid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/local/lib64/libuuid.a", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/lib64/libuuid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/lib64/libuuid.a", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/libuuid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib/libuuid.a", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/local/lib/libuuid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/local/lib/libuuid.a", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/lib/libuuid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/lib/libuuid.a", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/lib/libuuid.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 21920] open("/usr/lib/libuuid.a", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I understand the mechanism of a soft link from a file like `/usr/lib64/libuuid.so` (without the `.1` suffix) to a specific version, say, `libuuid.so.1.3.0`  The linker actually does a `readlink()`, I believe, to find out the ultimate file that `libuuid.so` points to, and embeds the target of that link `libuuid.so.1.3.0` into the binary.  That way, even should the "latest" version of uuid become 1.4.0 in the future, and `libuuid.so` be re-pointed to that new version, for example, this binary would still be linked with 1.3.0 at runtime.

But how is the compiler meant to get from `libuuid.so` to `libuuid.so.1`?

Comment: On my filesystem it is symlink as well `/usr/lib64/libuuid.so -> libuuid.so.1.3.0`

Answer (score 3):

you need to install `libuuid-devel` which contains:

```
/usr/lib64/libuuid.so -> libuuid.so.1.3.0
```

and the header files you probably need.

After compilation, your binary knows that he has been built with `libuuid.so.1`, so at execution he will not need `libuuid.so` but `libuuid.so.1`...